# carga de iconos font awesome

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sass, font-awesome, fuentes

estoy teniendo problemas con la carga de los iconos con font awesome 
y al utilizarlo me lo pone como esto:  
De esta manera cargo los iconos.

```
<!-- CARGANDO FUENTES -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet"> 
<!-- CARGANDO ICONOS -->
<link href="css/fontawesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Cabe mensionar que estoy utilizando sass, y de precompilador utilizo Koala.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Agregue las fuentes en mi proyecto.
desde el directorio de "web-fonts-with-css"
que incluye css y las fuentes.

este es el directorio del proyecto. que agregue el archivo "fontawesome.css" del css del directorio "web-fonts-with-css", al de "css" del proyecto.
alguien tiene alguna idea..
gracias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes verificar si en la consola te notifica algún error con las rutas de los archivos? ¿Cómo estás usando los iconos?, pon un ejemplo del código.

Comment: Muestra tu código html ya que podría estar pasándote lo mismo que ami, que en la clase colocaba fa-search cuando debería ser fa fa-search.

Comment: @A. Cedano, no tengo ningun error en la consola. simplemente no reconoce la fuente, de igual manera si esta cargando el archivo fontawesome.css, ya que en resources de la consola de desarrollo.

Comment: @YoAlbert    <button class="boton-menu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></button> literalmente copie el codigo de ejemplo que proporciona la pagina de fontawesome.

Comment: Juan, tienes un error: `<i class="fas fa-bars">`, debería  ser  `fa`, pero tú tienes `fas`: **`<i class="fa fa-bars">`**

Comment: @A.Cedano, tampoco funcioa. lo acabo de corregir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Juan, debes tener un problema sea con el archivo de fontawesome que estás usando, sea con restricciones del navegador, o con las rutas u otra cosa.

De todos modos en la [página de FA](https://fontawesome.com/get-started/svg-with-js), ellos dan una opción de instalar mediante un archivo javascript que se encargará de cargar los iconos en local.

He probado con ese solo archivo y el código me ha funcionado.

Esto es lo que dice la página:

## Descargar, personalizar y servirse

Obtenga una copia de la última versión de Font Awesome y utilícela junto con el código fuente de su propio proyecto mientras crea localmente y sirve en producción.

### 1. Agarra y mueve el `fontawesome-all.js` a tu proyecto.

El `fontawesome-all.js` carga todas las funciones básicas, además de todos los estilos visuales que necesitará cuando use Font Awesome. Cópielo en el directorio de activos estáticos de su proyecto (o donde quiera que prefiera mantener los activos de front-end o las cosas de los proveedores). Asegúrese de recordar la ruta de referencia.

### 2. Haga referencia al archivo `fontawesome-all.js`

Agregue una referencia al archivo `fontawesome-all.js` dentro del `<head>` de cada plantilla o página en la que quiera utilizar Font Awesome. Preste atención a la ruta de su proyecto y hacia dónde movió los archivos en el paso anterior.

### 3. Coloque iconos en el marcado de su UI

Con la referencia completa, ahora puede comenzar a colocar iconos en el `<body>` de su HTML. Recomendamos usar un elemento HTML consistente, como un `<i>`. Agregue dos clases al elemento: una que indique qué estilo usar (el estilo-prefijo) y la otra que llama al icono específico (nombre-icono).

### 4. Agregue [más awesome](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js)

Eche un vistazo a nuestro [estilo adicional](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js#additional-styling) para conocer más formas de diseñar sus iconos. Vaya más allá y use [transformaciones de potencia](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js#power-transforms) para crear capas de enmascaramiento y superposiciones.

---

He probado descargando el JS indicado más arriba y luego he usado el código HTML que ellos muestran:

```
<head>
  <!--load everything-->
  <script defer src="/static/fontawesome/fontawesome-all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!--user icon in two different styles-->
  <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
  <i class="far fa-user"></i>
  <!--brand icon-->
  <i class="fab fa-github-square"></i>
</body>
```

Efectivamente, los iconos se muestran correctamente haciendo referencia solamente a ese archivo javascript.

---

En cuanto a la sintaxis del código, no había error, el código funciona tal y como lo tienes, he aquí unas pruebas. El primero es el código que pusiste en comentario. Y luego, hay más pruebas. En este caso he usado este archivo: `https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css`

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button class="boton-menu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></button>

<div style="font-size:3em; color:Tomato">
  <i class="fas fa-camera-retro"></i>
</div>

<i class="fab fa-font-awesome"> 
<button>Open up <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>

<div class="fa-3x">
  <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-circle-notch fa-spin"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-sync fa-spin"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-cog fa-spin"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i>
</div>

<ul class="fa-ul">
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i></span>List icons can</li>
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i></span>be used to</li>
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i></span>replace bullets</li>
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="far fa-square"></i></span>in lists</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: A. Cedano ya lo corregi, no buscaba la ruta de las fuentes. no me indicaba nada. hasta que copie el css. del link... segun esta debe ser la ruta de las fuentes: url(../webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2) por eso no lo cargaba correctamente. gracias

Comment: @JuanL Me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: **[¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)** en el Centro de Ayuda.